# Syntax error on token "<", invalid AssignementOperato

Tags: java

I've search all over google but didn't found any fix... Here's the code:

```
public Command getCommandbyAlias(String alias)
{
    int length;
    int i;
    for (Iterator localIterator = getCommands().iterator(); localIterator.hasNext(); i < length)  //Here, at i < length
    {
        Command cmd = (Command)localIterator.next();
        String[] alias2;
        length = (alias2 = cmd.getAlias()).length;
        i = 0;
        continue;

        String aliases = alias2[i];
        Utils.addChatMessage(aliases);
        if (aliases.equalsIgnoreCase(alias)) {
            return cmd;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your third argument to `for` is a comparison, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two conditions in your `for` statement, you should use the `&&` boolean operator to join them to a single condition:

```
for (Iterator localIterator = getCommands().iterator(); 
     localIterator.hasNext() && i < length) {
```

Note, by the way, that you should initialize `i` and `length` before you try to use them. You current code does not.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try something for initializing them as they are already in the for loop =)

Answer (score 1):

Your third argument in the for loop is incorrect. I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
for (Iterator localIterator = getCommands().iterator(); localIterator.hasNext() && i < length; )
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)s

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

the third arguement is reserved for increment/decrement statements and it is optional

if you are confused about using for loop then go for `while` as per below code

```
Iterator localIterator = getCommands().iterator();
while(localIterator.hasNext() && i < length)

{
    Command cmd = (Command)localIterator.next();
    String[] alias2;
    length = (alias2 = cmd.getAlias()).length;
    i = 0;
    continue;

    String aliases = alias2[i];
    Utils.addChatMessage(aliases);
    if (aliases.equalsIgnoreCase(alias)) {
        return cmd;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Command getCommandbyAlias(String alias)
{
    int length;
    int i;
    Iterator localIterator = getCommands().iterator();
    while (localIterator.hasNext() && i < length)
    {
        Command cmd = (Command)localIterator.next();
        String[] alias2;
        length = (alias2 = cmd.getAlias()).length;
        i = 0;
        continue;

        String aliases = alias2[i];
        Utils.addChatMessage(aliases);
        if (aliases.equalsIgnoreCase(alias)) {
            return cmd;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return null;
}
```